# Related rates problem involving angles

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A picture 4ft high is placed on a wall with its base 3ft. above the eye of an observer. If the observer is approaching the wall at the rate of 4ft/sec, how fast is the measure of the angle subtended at his eye by the picture increasing when he is 10 ft. from the wall?

I am having trouble visualizing this problem, if someone could help me draw this picture I might be able to get started. I'll ask any further questions if I need assistance after that. thanks

Comment: The picture is supposed to have very very small width, indeed $0$ width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base of a triangle is the vertical dimension of the picture. The apex is the eye. You are not given the height of the eye, but I believe it is intended to be $5.5$ feet, which makes the triangle isosceles. The altitude is $10$ feet and decreasing.

Comment: is it an isosceles pyramid as the picture for the base?

Comment: This is a $2$D problem, which is why I talked of a triangle . Nothing is happening in the horizontal axis parallel to the wall.

Comment: well I was able to get the problem, thanks for help. I can't upvote you because my rep is low. Since you gave me the answer I was looking for, i'll put as answer.

Comment: Glad to help.  I try to help people work these out-I think it helps more for the future.  I was on my phone, so couldn't draw it.